# Delphi create frame that is in a package

Tags: delphi, package, frames

today I've a question about frames that are in packages.
I've a package that contains a simple frame:

```
unit fraMain;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,
  System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs,
  Vcl.StdCtrls;

type

  TFrame1 = class(TFrame)
    Label1: TLabel;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

initialization
  RegisterClass(TFrame1);

finalization
  UnRegisterClass(TFrame1);

end.
```

I've create the package and a new projexct that use it. The project has a simple form and it's code is this:

```
unit main;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,
  System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.Menus,
  System.Actions, Vcl.ActnList, Vcl.PlatformDefaultStyleActnCtrls, Vcl.ActnMan,
  Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TfrmMain = class(TForm)
    mnuMain: TMainMenu;
    mnuFile: TMenuItem;
    mnuModuli: TMenuItem;
    mFilCloseModules: TMenuItem;
    mModModulo1: TMenuItem;
    mModModulo2: TMenuItem;
    N1: TMenuItem;
    mFilExit: TMenuItem;
    actManager: TActionManager;
    actExit: TAction;
    actModulo1: TAction;
    actModulo2: TAction;
    procedure actExitExecute(Sender: TObject);
    procedure actModulo1Execute(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FPackageHandle: Integer;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

const
  DIRPACK1 = 'C:\Users...';

var
  frmMain: TfrmMain;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}


{ Chiusura applicazione }
procedure TfrmMain.actExitExecute(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Application.Terminate;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.actModulo1Execute(Sender: TObject);
var
  AClass: TClass;
  AFrame: TFrame;
begin
  if FPackageHandle = 0 then begin
    FPackageHandle := LoadPackage(DIRPACK1 + 'Pack_01.bpl');
    AClass := GetClass('TFrame1');
    if AClass <> nil then begin

    end;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Where DIRPACK1 is the path of where the bpl is.
In the "actModulo1Execute" action I would like to create the frame. As you can see I get the class, but after I don't know how to instantiate the frame.
Which is the manner for create the frame?

Comment: Why are you loading the package this way? That's your fundamental problem. Load it dynamically and you don't have access to the types. Why don't you load it statically? Then all your problems disappear. Why don't you stop using packages and make your life even easier? Note that `GetClass('TFrame1')` is going to look in the calling executable, and not your package.

Comment: Hi David, my intention is t realize a modular application so some features can be available for a group of users and others to another group. I thought, for this reason, to create sone packages each one qith the required features.

Comment: That's a really arduous way to do it. I wouldn't regard dynamically loaded packages as fit for purpose.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan `GetClass` will find the class from the loaded package if the package calls `RegisterClass` in its initialization, as is done here.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The arguments for dynamic loading of packages are the same as for dynamic loading of DLLs (late binding).  If the application is modular and not all users will have, want, or need the functionality in all supported packages then this is the way to do it.  A `.bpl` may be an odd vehicle for a plug-in type of architecture, but it nevertheless serves the same purpose.  Surely there are some legitimate uses cases here...

Comment: @J... The issue is that you don't have compile time access to any types defined in the package when loaded dynamically. You give up type safety. Very hard to see the benefit over a monolithic design with functionality that can be disabled at runtime.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Dynamically loading packages does not automatically give up type safety. There can be a base runtime package, a kind of API, required by the host application and all dynamic packages, where all relevant types are declared, and therefore known at compile time in all projects. (In RAD Studio, `designide` is an example of this.)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I won't dispute that dynamic packages come with major disadvantages.  We can still imagine cases where a monolithic design is either not possible or not practical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example:

```
  AClass := GetClass('TFrame1');
  if Assigned(AClass) and AClass.InheritsFrom(TCustomFrame) then
  begin
    AFrame := TCustomFrameClass(AClass).Create(Self);
    AFrame.Parent := Self;
    AFrame.Align := alClient;
    AFrame.Show;
  end;
```

If you don't want to use `RegisterClass` then another possible way is this:

```
  AClass := GetProcAddress(FPackageHandle, '@fraMain@TFrame1@');
```

(the convention is `<at><unit_name><at><class_name><at>`).

Comment: It is also critically important that the host executable be compiled with runtime packages enabled and that, at very least, the `rtl` and `vcl` packages are included among them.  Otherwise `RegisterClass` and `GetClass` will be called in different contexts (the package using the runtime `.dcp` and the host using the RTL source) and finding the class will fail.